# Importing a file in python in raspberry pi

Tags: python, import, module

I have no idea why my import doesnt work.

My folder structure

```
Garage_Parking
    __init__.py
    database.py

    rpi_components
        __init__.py
        NFC_Security.py
```

I want to import database in NFC_Security.py. 
I typed

```
from Garage_Parking import database
```

It just keep giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "NFC_Security.py", line 6, in <module>
from Garage_Parking import database
```

ImportError: No module named Garage_Parking

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It is important so specify which version of Python you're using here. The `import` mechanism was changed in Python 3.

Comment: @RolandSmith, when I do python --version is 2.7.9. But when I do a dpkg -l python3, there is a python 3.4 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to add the path of the parent folder to the *python path* so that the interpreter knows that it should look for files and modules even in the parent directory.

```
import os,sys
current_directory = os.getcwd()
parent_directory = os.path.dirname(current_directory)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_directory)
```

The code above adds the parent directory to the python path. Now you can freely import all modules from the parent folder.
Complete code for your specific case:

```
import os,sys
current_directory = os.getcwd()
parent_directory = os.path.dirname(current_directory)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_directory)

import database
```

For more information visit
[Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the main file with the rest of the files and then doing `import database`. It is the easy way. If you would like to keep your folder organization, I can’t help you.

Comment: When the files are growing in numbers gradually, is not wise to put it all in one folder.

Comment: I use this method when i have 1 or 2 files extra